# Game not running after start button is pressed

Tags: unity-game-engine

There are no compile errors or warnings. My game just starts paused. I can look around but everything is frozen. I even tried to call `Time.timeScale = 1;` from various start functions. "Error on Pause" is turned off.

Restarting Unity has no effect.

Why is this happening?

HINT:
I figured out that calling `Time.timeScale = 1;` was not working because the gameObject where the script was attached to, was not set to active.

Comment: What do you mean by "freezed"?  The Editor is frozen or the game is frozen? Can you click on Unity menu like GameObject --->Create Empty?

Comment: Yes, the game starts paused. I can look around but grass is not animating and rigid body objects placed in the air are not falling

Comment: I don't see how replying with "Yes" answered my first question....

Comment: I was answering with more than just three words.

Comment: Is the pause button clicked in the editor? If clicked before play, the scene will start paused

Comment: No, it is not clicked.

Comment: And it doesn't look clicked while playing? If so, then pause doesn't seem to be the right word. It seems like Time.timescale is 0... are you setting it to zero anywhere?

Comment: Yes I was setting it to 0 after the player opened my menu by pressing ESC, but even If comment out every single occurence of `Time.timeScale` in my whole project, then it still starts paused. I used notepad++ to search the whole project.

Comment: I answered below :)

Comment: @Programmer Could you possibly edit the question please? This one is actually a pretty hard to solve issue with few resources, and this question is inaccurate (time-scale is zero, the editor isn't paused)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your Time Manager. Sometimes it gets randomly corrupted and the scale drops to Zero. 
Time Manager (menu: Edit > Project Settings > Time)

Comment: Thank you so much, that was solving it :)

Comment: Untested theory, but the "corruption" may be due to exiting the game, closing the game, or crashing while time scale is currently zero, but i have a feeling that I've had it occur in games where I never touched the time scale...

Comment: A great tip - but it wasn't it for me!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to force unpause in script?

```
EditorApplication.isPlaying = true;
```

Game can start paused also because of some unknown problems with assests so you can try to reimport them. If it doesn't help your next move should be to reinstall unity.

Also make sure you don't do some very time consuming operations on `Awake()` and `Start()`.

Comment: *"Game can start paused also because of some unknown problems with assests so you can try to reimport them"* Not sure where you got this from...

Comment: [link]http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/29176/when-i-press-play-it-just-pauses-right-after.html

Also I encauntered similar problem while writing my application and my assets were somehow imported with error that didn't display, reimport helped.

Comment: My bad, Unity moved it to `EditorApplication.isPlaying`

Comment: But how should I force it to unpause by using a getter?

Comment: EditorApplication's is not read-only (or at least isPaused is not). Also, if the pause button isn't showing in your editor, you're not paused

Comment: `EditorApplication.isPlaying` is both setter and getter, I just checked it in my Unity. Also as @Mars just pointed out, as your pause button is not checked your game isn't paused.

Comment: Ok, I tried `EditorApplication.isPlaying = true` but this does not work either. However, I noticed that if I unhide my gameObject where the script is attached to, then I can start the game by calling `Time.timeScale = 1`. But why do I even have to force the timeScale to 1 even though it is not overwritten at start?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has this error and the described solutions have not helped, check that the Editors Pause on Error option is not checked. If you go the console window you will see that tab option highlighted at the top of the window if it is on, unticking that will allow the game to play if it is starting paused because of an error. This option being turned on would likely be your issue if the issue replicates across different projects.